# How to go from DataTable to csv of a single column

Tags: c#

I'm trying to take a single column in my DataTable and turn the values into a CSV string. I know I can loop through the DataTable with for each but I'd like to do it the cool way with Linq.

I would like a CSV string of all the customer names in the table.

For example:

```
"Tom,Mary,Tad,Lad,Ben"
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/bmkCxk

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyDataTable");

        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("CustomerName", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "Tom");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mary");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Tad");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "Lad");
        dt.Rows.Add(5, "Ben");

        Console.WriteLine($"{dt.Rows[0]["CustomerName"]}");

        var result = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(x => x["CustomerName"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine($"CSV display {result}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rod. I wonder if I can give some posting advice. The phrasing of a number of your questions seem to be asking for readers to finish your work. They are "please give me your insight", "please help me", and in this case "please do it for me". They seem to lack personal agency, as if you have given up in each case. We prefer technical writing here, so I would advocate for a greater level of succinctness, and readers probably don't want to wade through paragraphs of pleading.

Comment: Moreover, you may find it personally helpful to reword things for yourself - in a way, this persuades you that you can do it. It also reassures readers that you are not dumping a problem onto volunteers. So, questions could be "How can I do this?", "How can I fix this?", "What do I need to do to achieve X?". This reflects a greater level of agency, both to readers and to yourself.

Comment: @halfer, thank you for the feedback, I appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. I should have mentioned also that the above can be the cause of some downvotes, and phrasing something differently can drastically improve the reception a question receives. There's been some interesting discussions on _Meta Stack Overflow_ about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) to complete it.

```
var yourCsvLine = string.Join(",", dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(x => x["CustomerName"].ToString()));
```

Comment: Given the use case I think you need `string.Join("\r\n", etc)` instead of using a comma. There is only one column but multiple lines.

Comment: @JohnWu - maybe but the way I read it is comma separate the names on one line. Otherwise, if there is only 1 value per line, the fact that it should be CSV then no longer matters. Too bad there is no expected output in the question...